# Kperf result of scale is error: failed to get the cluster endpoint: http2 port of ingress service not found

Tags: kubernetes, contour, knative

Im trying to run `kperf service scale` or `load` doesnt work due to the following error. I am using Contour as networking layer and I have 2 namespaces, Contour-internal and contour-external. Both result in the same error. I don't understand what exactly the error means, as I have no ingresses for my services, just classic k8s svcs with http2 ports.

Help is appreciated.

```
$ GATEWAY_OVERRIDE=contour GATEWAY_NAMESPACE_OVERRIDE=contour-internal kperf service scale --namespace test-kn --svc-prefix ksvc --range 0,1  --verbose --output /tmp -i 20 -T 10s -s 6s
scale up service core-kn/ksvc-0 in 20 iterations:
scale up service core-kn/ksvc-1 in 20 iterations:
result of scale is error: failed to get the cluster endpoint: http2 port of ingress service not foundresult of scale is error: failed to get the cluster endpoint: http2 port of ingress service not foundMeasurement saved in CSV file /tmp/20230707151258_ksvc_scaling_time.csv
Visualized measurement saved in HTML file /tmp/20230707151258_ksvc_scaling_time.html
Measurement saved in JSON file /tmp/20230707151258_ksvc_scaling_time.json
```

### Steps to reproduce

1. Instal Knative operator and components
2. Use Contour as networking layer
3. Create services using kperf
4. run kperf service scale/load with GATEWAT_OVERRIDE and GATEWAY_NAMESPACE_OVERRIDE accordingly